# ¿Renderizar una cadena con elementos HTML?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Mi inquietud es que tengo una cadena en mi base de datos de la siguiente forma:

```
'<a href="#" id="Manuel">@Manuel</a>&nbsp;hola'
```

Cuando la tengo en mi modelo aparece de la misma forma, y cuando quiero renderizar la vista se muestra talcual esta en la base de datos, lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
<div>@Model.evento[0].Notas_Inicio</div>
```

**¿Como puedo mostrarla como si perteneciera al `DOM` de la pagina?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que hice fue cambiar la forma de mostrar la cadena, para eso utilice [HtmlHelper.Raw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.98).aspx) de `Razor`.

Entonces mi `div` quedo de la siguiente forma:

```
<div>@Html.Raw(@Model.evento[0].Notas_Inicio)</div>
```

> **Advertencia:** si `Notas_Inicio` puede ser modificada por un usuario, esto abre la posibilidad que inserten código arbitrario a tu página como scripts maliciosos. - [Equiso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33239/renderizar-una-cadena-con-elementos-html/33240#comment55932_33240)

Comment: Márcala como correcta.

Comment: **Advertencia**, si `Notas_Inicio` puede ser modificada por un usuario, esto abre la posibilidad que inserten código arbitrario a tu página como scripts maliciosos.